# Numerical fluctuations in the plot

Tags: numerics

I have a code, which contains some numerical values, the code is as follow

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
\[CapitalGamma] = 50;
 G\[Mu] = 10^-10;
\[Alpha] = 0.3688566917981026`;
 \[Xi]r = 0.271108;
 c = 0.23;
 a0 = 1;
\[CapitalOmega]m = 0.3153;
\[CapitalOmega]r = 9.21871*10^-5;
 h = 0.6736;
H0 = ((100*10^3*h)/(3.08568*10^22))(*1 MPc=3,086*10^22*);
tpl = 5.39*10^-44(*sec*);
\[Nu]r = 0.662062;
 \[Nu]m = 0.582512;
\[Xi]m = 0.625363;
 \[ScriptCapitalF] = 0.1;
  \[CapitalOmega]0m = \[CapitalOmega]m;
 aeq = a0 \[CapitalOmega]r/\[CapitalOmega]m;
 zeq = a0/aeq - 1;
 \[Epsilon]r = (\[Alpha]*\[Xi]r)/(\[CapitalGamma]*G\[Mu]);
 \[Epsilon]m = (\[Alpha]*\[Xi]m)/(\[CapitalGamma]*G\[Mu]);
 Cr = c*\[Nu]r/(
  Sqrt[2] \[Alpha]*\[Xi]r^4) (\[Alpha]*\[Xi]r + \[CapitalGamma]* G\[Mu])^(3 (1 - 1/2));
  H0m = H0*\[CapitalOmega]0m^(1/2);
  teq = (2 (2 - Sqrt[2]))/(3*H0*Sqrt[\[CapitalOmega]m]) (aeq/a0)^(3/2);
\[ScriptCapitalA]rm = Sqrt[128/3] \[Pi]* \[ScriptCapitalF] *Cr*(h^2*\ 
[CapitalOmega]0m)/((1 + zeq)^3 (H0m*teq)^(3/2)) (G\[Mu]/\[CapitalGamma])^(1/2);
 S1rmxs = (2 + 3*xs)/(Sqrt[xs] (1 + xs)^(3/2));
 S1rmxe = (2 + 3*xe)/(Sqrt[xe] (1 + xe)^(3/2));
  xs = If[xeqm > Re[\[Phi]3[xtinim, \[Epsilon]r]], xeqm, 
  Re[\[Phi]3[xtinim, \[Epsilon]r]]];
 xe = If[x0m > Re[\[Phi]3[xteqm, \[Epsilon]r]], 
 Re[\[Phi]3[xteqm, \[Epsilon]r]], x0m];
x0m = f/f0m;
f0m = h0m;
h0m = (3*H0m)/(\[CapitalGamma]*G\[Mu]);
xeqm = f/feqm;
feqm = Sqrt[a0/aeq] h0m;
xteqm = f/fteqm;
fteqm = (a0/ateqm)^(1/2) h0m;
ateqm = atmeq;
atmeq = a0 (3/2 H0m *teq)^(2/3);
xtinim = f/ftinim;
ftinim = (a0/atinim)^(1/2) h0m;
atinim = atmini;
atmini = a0 (3/2 H0m*tini)^(2/3);
tini = 1/(2*H0*Sqrt[\[CapitalOmega]r]) (ai/a0)^2;
ai = (Sqrt[2] a0 Sqrt[H0] Sqrt[tpl] \[CapitalOmega]r^(1/4))/G\[Mu];
\[Epsilon]r = (\[Alpha]*\[Xi]r)/(\[CapitalGamma]*G\[Mu]);
\[Phi]3[x_, \[Epsilon]_] = 1/3 (-1 + 2^(1/3)/(\[Phi][x, \[Epsilon]])^(
 1/3) + (\[Phi][x, \[Epsilon]])^(1/3)/2^(1/3));
 \[Phi][x_, \[Epsilon]_] = -2 + 27*(1 + \[Epsilon]) x^3 + 3 Sqrt[3]
 Sqrt[-4 (1 + \[Epsilon]) x^3 + 27 ((1 + \[Epsilon]) x^3)^2];
 wsrm = (h0m/f xs)^(1/2);
 werm = (h0m/f xe)^(1/2);
 h2\[CapitalOmega]rmKai[f_] = \[ScriptCapitalA]rm *(wsrm*S1rmxs - werm*S1rmxe);
```

When plotting the final expression,

```
LogLogPlot[h2\[CapitalOmega]rmKai[f], {f, 10^-29, 10^10},Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {HoldForm[f[Hz]], HoldForm[h^2 Subscript[\[CapitalOmega], GW]]},PlotRange -> {{10^-22,10^15}, {1*10^-29, 10^-7}}, FrameStyle -> Directive[Black, Small], PlotStyle -> {Darker[Cyan]},LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], ImageSize -> Large]
```

I have a plot like,
[image]

I just want to get rid of the numerical fluctuations at low frequencies. Can anyone please guide how to do this?
Thank you

Comment: The fluctuations are perhaps caused by round off errors.  If this is the case, you would need to ensure that Mathematica uses higher precision in the relevant parts of the calculation.  As a starting point, you can try giving the `LogLogPlot` something like `WorkingPrecision->30`.  If that doesn't fix it, you could try ensure that Mathematica treats all your constants as having higher precision.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried the ´WorkingPrecision´ but it's not working. Regarding your second suggestion, I didn't understand that how I can make Mathematica treat all constants as having higher precision. Can you please elaborate it bit more with some code?

Comment: Something like `SetPrecision[0.23, 30]`

Comment: It is also not making any difference still I have the same noise.

Comment: So by using both `SetPrecision` and `WorkingPrecision` I have resolved the issue. Thanks for the help.